# Signup page validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I want to create simplest validation for my signup form. My signup form contains input fields with default values. It must check for values of the fields. If user doesn't change default value of the field the script must alert about it.

How can I do it? My signup form looks like that: http://pastie.org/2369498 and reg.js: http://pastie.org/2369500

Comment: Both of these links are now dead, and thuus the question must be put on hold or removed. Are you able to remove it Tural? It is not possible for it to help future readers unless by chance you have an exact copy of the old files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged your question with jQuery, so I'll give you a jQuery answer. You can get the value of a field using the `val` method:

`$("#someField").val();`

You can then compare the current value of the field with your default value, and perform some action if that's the case:

```
if($("#someField").val() === "Default") {
    $("#errorMessage").text("You must enter someField.");
}
```

You could also look into the jQuery [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

*Update* (based on comments)

You can get the value of the selected radio button the same way as shown above, with the `val` method:

```
var selectedType = $("input[name=type]").val();
switch(selectedType) {
    case "1":
        //Validate required fields as shown above
        break;
    case "2":
        //Validate next lot of fields
        break;
    //Continue with as many sections as you have.
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for fast answer. I have few more questions.  I have radio buttons with name "type" as you see. When some of them
is checked then appears hidden div. There are 2-3 fields within these hidden divs. I want to create something like that with js (example shown in php style):
`
        if(type==1)
        {
        check input fields of div "scholar" 
        }
        if(type==2)
        {
        check input fields of div "abt" 
        }` how to do it?